# System.currentTimeMillis exchange Java software and Android

Tags: java, android, database, timezone, derby

I try to exchange informations beetween my java software and an android tool. I put `System.currentTimeMillis()` form my android tool to a Derby database. 
I'm at UTC -4.

On software:
When it's `Aug 09 2016 08:32:32`
long is : `1470745952393`
That means `Aug 09 2016 12:32:32 UTC`

On Android
When shows `Aug 09 2016 08:44:37`
it saved `1470732277580`
that means `Aug 09 2016 04:44:37` for my time zone...

Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: 8+4=12, 8-4=4 => you are on UTC-4, the Android tool is working with UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your software locale is different from the one on your device. Check on both devices:

`java.util.TimeZone.getDefault()`

and see what it returns.

Comment: On android : id=GMT,offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=false... and software : d="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,

Comment: Yep. So there you have it. Two timezones are different, so the long is interpretted differently. Possible solution is format the date: `DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, YOUR_LOCALE);
String formattedDate = df.format(yourDate);`